# Use SP OOB Ribbon Buttons in a own Custom Ribbon Tab

Tags: 2010, ribbon

I want to import some OOB Buttons to my custom ribbon tab, following this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/aa8241e5-0189-486e-84cf-27b94dc2c2e5) steps I was able to show exactly the buttons as it should, however, the commands and tooltips are not working and every time I unselected my custom tab the 'imported' buttons simply disappear. There is some extra further steps?

spregards.

---

Code Blocks:

```
<MaxSize Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Share.MaxSize" GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab.Share" Size="OneLarge" Sequence="6" />
<Scale Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Share.Scaling.CustomTabScaling" GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab.Share" Size="OneLarge" Sequence="12"  />
```

(...)

```
                            <Group
                                Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Share"
                                Sequence="30"
                                Command="ShareGroup"
                                Description=""
                                Title="$Resources:core,cui_GrpShare;"
                                Image32by32Popup="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32PopupTop="-128" Image32by32PopupLeft="-64"
                                Template="Ribbon.Templates.OneLargeExample">
                                <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Share.Controls">
                                    <Button
                                      Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Share.EmailPageLink"
                                      Sequence="10"
                                      Command="EmailPageUrl"
                                      Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-16" Image16by16Left="-88"
                                      Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-128" Image32by32Left="-448"
                                      LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButEmailLink;"
                                      ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButEmailLink;"
                                      ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButEmailLinkPage;"
                                      TemplateAlias="cust1" />
                                </Controls>
                            </Group>
```

(...)

```
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
                <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.OneLargeExample">
                    <Layout Title="OneLarge"
                            LayoutTitle="OneLarge">
                        <Section Alignment="Top"
                                Type="OneRow">
                            <Row>
                                <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large"
                                        TemplateAlias="cust1" />
                            </Row>
                        </Section>
                    </Layout>
                </GroupTemplate>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
```

---

*Update:*

This could be an problem of core.js reference, cause it works when I change the SP installation language.

Comment: Most often this is a problem with the XML of the custom action you defined. Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: sure! btw, I'm trimming the original tab of the 'imported' buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused some cache or misguided reference to the core.js

here some links that could be helpful:

[link1](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/11/avoiding-bugs-from-cached-javascript.html)
[link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606.aspx)